# nabla operator under the integral sign

Tags: integration, derivatives

I searched the stackexchange pages but still have problems with solving my problem. I have to calculate the following integral:

$$
g =\int d\boldsymbol{r'} \frac{\rho(\boldsymbol{r'})}{ |\boldsymbol{r}-\boldsymbol{r'}|}\mathrm{exp}\left(c|\boldsymbol{r}-\boldsymbol{r'}|\right)
$$

and the gradient $\nabla g$. First of all, I would say the integrand is not continuous (at $\boldsymbol{r}=\boldsymbol{r}'$). So the integrand is not Riemann integrable...But nevertheless a Cauchy integral can be calculated. I read, that differentiation under the integral sign, i.e.

$$
\nabla g =\int d\boldsymbol{r'} \rho(\boldsymbol{r'}) \nabla \left\{\frac{1}{ |\boldsymbol{r}-\boldsymbol{r'}|}\mathrm{exp}\left(c|\boldsymbol{r}-\boldsymbol{r'}|\right)\right\},
$$

is only possible, when the integrand is continuous. However, in this case the integrand is not continuous, so is the operation not right? Nevertheless, all electrodynamics books put the nabla operator inside the integral (of course then without the exponential function)

Comment: Does no one have an idea?